What is the global dimension of the ring $\prod_I k$, where $k$ is a field and $I$ is an infinite index set?
Let $k$ be a field.
If $I$ is a finite index set, then the global dimension of the ring $\prod_I k$ is zero because $\prod_I k$ is a semisimple ring.
Now, the question arises: When $I$ is an infinite index set, what is the global dimension of the ring $\prod_I k$?
For instance, when $ I = $ $\aleph_1 $, what is $ \mathrm{gl. dim} \prod_{\aleph_1} k $?

I would not be surprised if this is not decidable in ZFC, because of this.

Actually, now I see that the wiki page already answers your question for countable $I$. It says that then $k^I$ has global dimension $2$ iff the continuum hypothesis holds. This of course is compatible with Jeremy's answer.

By Theorem 2.51 of
Osofsky, Barbara L., Homological dimensions of modules, Conference Board of the Mathematical Sciences. Regional Conference Series in Mathematics. No. 12. Providence, R.I.: American Mathematical Society (AMS). VIII,89 p. (1973). ZBL0254.13015,
the global dimension of $\prod_Ik$ is $d+1$ if $\vert2^I\vert=\aleph_d$ (and infinite if $\vert2^I\vert>\aleph_d$ for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$).
So if the generalized continuum hypothesis is true, and $\vert I\vert=\aleph_1$, then the global dimension of $\prod_Ik$ is $3$.
